# pymssql intersect error - Cannot call methods on int

Tags: python, sql-server, pymssql

I have a SQL Statement which works fine when I use Server Managament Studio and I get the correct output:

```
SELECT BEZ.[BEZNR6]
  FROM BEZ BEZ WHERE BEZ.Shape.STIntersects(geometry::Point(483889.0702499999, 5238377.560075896, 32633))= 1;
```

Now I wanted to use this in a Python(2.7.18) script with pymssql(2.1.5):

```
with conn.cursor(as_dict=True) as cursor:
    abfrage='''SELECT BEZ.[BEZNR6]
        FROM [bd].[bda].[BEZ] BEZ WHERE BEZ.Shape.STIntersects(geometry::Point(%s, %s, 32633))= 1'''
    cursor.execute(abfrage, (483889.0702499999, 5238377.560075896))
    query = cursor.fetchall()
```

I get an error msg:

```
pymssql.OperationalError: (258, 'Cannot call methods on int.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possibly using `geometry::Point(%s, %s, 32633)` will result in `geometry::Point('483889.0702499999', '5238377.560075896', 32633)` being in the query - note the single quotes. Have you tried using `%d` instead of `%s`?

Comment: I think you need to make sure that the parameter is passed as a number. What about `geometry::Point(:1, :2, 32633)`

Comment: yes i tried with %d same error, i also tried this ```cursor.execute(
    '''SELECT BEZ.[BEZNR6]
        FROM [bd].[bda].[BEZ] BEZ WHERE BEZ.[Shape].STIntersects(geometry::Point(483889.0702499999,5238377.560075896,32633))=1''')
    query=cursor.fetchall()```

Comment: Are you sure Python is connecting to the same SQL Server and database that you're testing against in SSMS? Is it possible that BEZ's `Shape` is actually an `int` column as the error message suggests?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the db user. The python script used a user with not enough permissions. Used an other user with more permissions, than the script works fine.